# How to package a Mac OS app with Pyinstaller that shows both a console and a GUI?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I'm packaging a GUI app for MacOS with Pyinstaller, using --windowed flag. Is it possible to package it so that it would show a console in addition to the GUI? When I tried to set console=True, the GUI part fails.

In other words, when I start the App from the terminal by typing "open My.App/Contents/MacOS/myapp", then I do get both GUI and console. I'd like to get similar behaviour by just double-clicking on the App without starting the terminal. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you found a way to do it?

Comment: @Irfanka -  no. I haven't been looking for solutions since I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

> while you create application don't add those options

**--windowed** and **--noconsole**